# EAR exported from One Websphere instance to another failed to start

Tags: java, ear, websphere-7

I have exported an EAR file from one IBM websphere environment (7.0) and installed in another environment. Though EAR file deploys without errors, it still fails to start.

Error message in admin client;

> Application `MyApplication` did not start successfully on all of the servers in cluster `CLUSTER001`. Check log for details.

Below is the log;

```
WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplication in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplication.
WSVR0200I: Starting application: MyApplication
WSVR0204I: Application: MyApplication  Application build level: Unknown
WSVR0206E: Module, MyApplication.war, of application, MyApplication.ear/deployments/MyApplication, failed to start
WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, MyApplication
WSVR0217I: Stopping application: MyApplication
WSVR0220I: Application stopped: MyApplication
WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplication in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplication failed to start.
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: In my case it failed when I have not completed required setup at Admin Console (internal queues) for this EAR to run.

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal Have you got any config steps for that?

Comment: You are using WAS ND and cluster, your nodes might not be fully synchronized. Synchronize nodes and make sure all cluster members are up.

Comment: Is there an earlier instance of WSVR0101W in that server's logs that has a corresponding FFDC with a message indicating what the error was that occurred while starting the application?

Answer (score 1):

Actual error was found in a txt file mentioned in NodeName_exception.log file inside ../ffdc.

"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppHostNotFoundException: CLUSTER001_VH_MYAPPLICATION"

Although the source environment had a custom virtual host name, the destination environment did not have and was using "default_host".

Solution :
In admin console ;
Applications>Websphere Applications>Click problematic app>Virtual hosts>re select default_host as virtual host>hit OK and start your application.

Alternatively in EAR inside ../WEB-INF ibm-web-bnd.xmi is auto generated. Try to change the virtualHostName as "default_host" and try to deploy. This I haven't tried but worth checking.